# Magento-Edit Product custom options deleted automatically after click on save/save & edit?

Tags: magento-1.9

I've added product with custom options programmatically. When I edit the product & save the added custom options deleted from saved product.

**Below is my code to insert product with custom options:**

```
$p = array(
    'sku_type' => 0,
    'sku' => 'SKU00'.$row['Pid'],
    'name' => $row['ProductName'],
    'description' => $row['Description'],
    'short_description' => $row['Description'],
    'type_id' => 'simple',
    'attribute_set_id' => 4,
    'weight' => 0.00,
    'visibility' => 4,
    'price_type' => 0,
    'price_view' => 0,
    'price' => $row['SPrice'],
    'status' => 1,
    'created_at' => strtotime('now'),
    'category_ids' => 2,
    'store_id' => 1,
    'website_ids' => 1,
    'tax_class_id' => 0,
);
$product->setData($p);
$optionRawData = array();
$optionRawData[0] = array(
    'required' => 1,
    'option_id' => '',
    'position' => 0,
    'type' => 'select',
    'title' => $row['ProductName'],
    'default_title' => $row['ProductName'],
    'delete' => '',
);

$selectionRawData = array();
$selectionRawData[0] = array();
$selectionRawData[0][] = array(
    'product_id' => $row['Product_Id'],
    'selection_qty' => 1,
    'selection_can_change_qty' => 100,
    'position' => 0,
    'is_default' => 1,
    'selection_id' => '',
    'selection_price_type' => 0,
    'selection_price_value' => $row['SPrice'],
    'option_id' => '',
    'delete' => ''
);

$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

// Set the Bundle Options & Selection Data
$product->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
$product->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);
$product->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$product->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);
$product->getResource()->save($product);
$productID = $product->getId();

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);

$optionsArray = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'Standard',
        'price' => 0.0,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => '',
        'sort_order' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Premium',
        'price' => 10,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => '',
        'sort_order' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'title' => 'Deluxe',
        'price' => 20,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => '',
        'sort_order' => 2,
    )
);

$options = array(
    'title' => $product->getName(),
    'type' => 'radio',
    'is_required' => 1,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'values' => $optionsArray,
);
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
$product->setHasOptions(1);
$optionInstance->addOption($options);
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$product->save();
```

Comment: Please post your code to know what you have done and analyse where it fails.

Comment: I've added by code. can you checked in anything wrong in that

Comment: do this give you product Id - $productCheck->getId();

Comment: I've updated the code. it gives me product id  $productID = $product->getId();

Comment: This might be one of the issue. Did you try running this again?

Comment: the script running successfully. the problem is when I edit the product & save it the custom options deleted automatically or not displaying. is any db entry is missing?